# Projectile motion sim, index out of bounds error, nested for/while loops

Tags: python, numpy, physics, nested-loops, index-error

I'm trying to graph the optimum angle of launch as a function of the mass and graph it.
for each element of `mlist` I want it to calculate the distance traveled for that `m` for each element of `thetalist`, then take the highest distance for that `m` and get the theta that gave that answer and make a new list of these so called `theta_optimum` and plot it vs `mlist`.

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np
import math
#############
Die = 10.0
B = 1.6e-4
b = B*Die
g = 9.81
tmax = 1000
dt = 0.01
v = 100.0
mlist = np.arange(1.0, 100.0, 1.0)
thetalist = np.arange(0.1, math.pi / 2.0, 0.1)
theta_op = []

for j in range(len(mlist)):
    for i in range(len(thetalist)):
        vy = math.sin(thetalist[i]) * v
        vx = math.cos(thetalist[i]) * v
        t = 0.0
        x = 0.0
        y = 0.0
        xlist = []
        while y >= 0.0:
            vx1 = -b/mlist[j]*vx
            vx = vx + vx1*dt
            dx = vx * dt
            x = x + dx

            vy1 = -g-b/mlist[j]*vy
            vy = vy + vy1 * dt
            dy = vy * dt
            y = y + dy

            t = t + dt

            xlist.append(x)

        theta_op.append(thetalist[xlist.index(max(xlist))])

plt.plot(mlist, theta_op, color='red')
plt.show()
```

The error I am getting is:

```
line 39, in <module>
theta_op.append(thetalist[xlist.index(max(xlist))])
IndexError: index 202 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 15
```

My question is how do I fix this error in my code and why has it arisen. I know the physics is right but as I am new to coding I am not sure if the way I have made my lists and loops is correct. I have looked for other questions like this but haven't found any.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. You're storing of every position the projectile has crossed. You end up with a very long list of positions, much longer than the number of angles. I think you want to just store the maximum position reached by each projectile, and then see which angle that corresponds to, right?

Comment: You might also want to use a more accurate integration algorithm than simple Euler, e.g. RK4.

Comment: Hi Guys, @meowgoesthedog this is for a class and i am restricted to this method sadly.

Comment: @beenjaminnn i have changed my resetting of the xlist and the appending of it so that it is appended after the while loop and reset just inside the first for loop., i am getting now that no matter what the mass the angle is 45.8366236105 degrees as far as i know the angle should increase with mass.

Comment: The angle should approach 45 degrees with increasing mass (since the effect of air resistance decreases in significance, while that of gravity does not change).

Comment: Also, why do you need to store *every* X-value? Just store the one at the end, with the corresponding value of theta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are *severely* mixing up your variable scopes.

For every value of mass and theta, you save *every* value of `x` during the integration procedure. Assuming that's what you wanted to do, you then wrote the line causing this error:

```
theta_op.append(thetalist[xlist.index(max(xlist))])
```

The above returns the index of the maximum value in `xlist`; you then uses this index to access `thetalist`, which makes *no sense at all*. The size of `thetalist` and `xlist` are *independent*, the former depending on the theta step, and the latter on the simulation time step; so using the index of one to access the other may well result in this overflow.

This brings us back to the question of *why* you want to save all x values in the first place. Why not just save the *last* x value for each value of theta, and get the optimum theta for each mass, which exactly matches your problem description?

```
for j in range(len(mlist)):

    best_theta = 0.0
    best_x = 0.0

    for i in range(len(thetalist)):

        # initialisation code as before
        # ...

        while y >= 0.0:
            # integration code as before
            # ...

        # update the best theta for this mass
        if x > best_x:
            best_theta = thetalist[i]
            best_x = x

    # add the best theta to theta_op without having to do any searches   
    theta_op.append(best_theta)
```

---

**EDIT**: I tested this code with various theta step values, and all results were within reasonable range of the zero-resistance limit (45 degrees = 0.785398... radians), so you may wish to consider increasing the drag coefficient.

Comment: The saving of each x value was a mistake on my part and has been fixed since it was pointed out. I have ran this code and the mass needs to be reduced as the effect is only for very small masses. thank you for your time

Comment: Sorry this is my first question. is it the tick?